# python: running a function without params

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

```
def calculateTotalSum(*arguments):
 if arguments != None:
   total = sum(arguments) / len(arguments)
   print("our average is",total)
  else:
   return 0

calculateTotalSum()
```

how can I run this function without passing in any arguments? I keep running into errors. Is there a way to check if nothing was passed?

Comment: in what scenario would you pass nothing in the first place?

Comment: Add `print(arguments)` to see what you get.

Comment: `arguments` is a list of the arguments passed.  If you pass no arguments, it will be the empty list, which is not the same as `None`.  You just want to check `if arguments:` to determine if there are arguments, the empty list is "false" in booleans.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `*args` will always be a `tuple`. The Pythonic way to check if a `tuple` is empty is to use its implicit conversion to `bool`.

```py
def calculateTotalSum(*arguments):
    if arguments:  # Evaluates to True => not empty.
        total = sum(arguments) / len(arguments)
        print("our average is", total)
    else:
        return 0

calculateTotalSum()
```

The same pattern applies to most types.

---

Although I've left the function as close to yours as possible, the inconsistencies in it will give you headaches later on. I'd strongly suggest taking better advantage of Exceptions and single-responsibility functions:

```py
def calculateAverage(*arguments):
    if not arguments:
        raise ValueError("Can not take the average of nothing")
    return sum(arguments) / len(arguments)


try:
    total = calculateAverage()
    print("our average is", total)
except ValueError:
    total = None
```